# Handle exception when placed @JsonFormat in json mapping file.Getting exception with 400

Tags: java, spring-boot, fasterxml

I have placed `@JsonFormat` annotation in my json mapping file while mapping from `json` To `class`. I am getting `HttpMessageNotReadableException` and `InvalidFormatException` exceptions with parse error message.

Below is the code for the reference:

```
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.List;

    import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
    import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;
    import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

    import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Email;

    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;

    import lombok.Getter;
    import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
    import lombok.Setter;
    import lombok.ToString;

    @Setter
    @Getter
    @ToString
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public class Request {

        @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
        private Date customerDOB;

    }
```

I have tried to handle above exceptions but getting `bad request(400)`. Please help me to handle above exception.

Comment: Please add more details regarding your problem, like adding more code, related information will help people understand issue better and provide solution effectively.

Comment: I have added
 @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")
 private Date customerDOB;
while parsing i am getting exception ,but on postman getting 400, if i am providing 2019-Mar-04 as customerDOB. I want message on postman instead of 400.

Comment: pass request data as 2019-03-04 and check

Comment: Server responding with 400 is correct. 400 is bad request and user should not repeat the request without any modification. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400

Comment: I want to handle 400 so that user can see what exact error is coming for that i have added
 
 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
 protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleMethodInvalidFormatException(InvalidFormatException ex, HttpHeaders headers,
   HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
  String errorCode = messageSource.getMessage("config.generic.errorCode", null, null);
  String errorMessage = ex.getMessage();
  return (ResponseEntity<Object>) createErrorResponse(errorCode, errorMessage, HttpStatus.OK);
 }

But still not able to handle exception

Answer (score 0):

How about you add an `@ExceptionHandler` for these exception and then you'll have full control on what status code and body to send back as the response